# Exporting Constants

Tags: reactjs, react-native, import

I have one file called types. It contains the following.

```
export default {
  CLEAR_STATE: 'CLEAR_STATE'
};
```

I want to import CLEAR_STATE, so I do a destructured import in my other file.

```
import { CLEAR_STATE } from './types';
```

This won't work in React Native, but it does work in regular React. Is there a way to make this work in React Native, or is it not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is the same for both React & React Native. It looks similar to destructuring, but it's not quite the same.

You are exporting an object as the default export, so you could do this:

```
import types from './types'
const { CLEAR_STATE } = types
```

or you could export `CLEAR_SLATE` as a named export instead of default:

```
export const CLEAR_SLATE = 'CLEAR_SLATE'
// or
const CLEAR_SLATE = 'CLEAR_SLATE'
export {
  CLEAR_STATE
}
```

then import by name:

```
import { CLEAR_SLATE } from './types'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try exporting the object as non-default?

Import lists will only work with explicit named exports and is not a de-structuring of the returned object.

Have a read here for a good and detailed explanation: http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html